# How do I display randomly an array without click on the button?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, random

I'd like to have a page with a button and when I click the button the text should be shown. the text is taken from different arrays randomly with Javascript. Everything works in my project except one thing:
On the first load of the page I see no text just the button. How do I make so that one of the arrays is randomly chosen and displayed on the fist page load (without click on the button)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var quotes = [{
                text: " <br>    1   <br><br>    2   <br><br>    3   ",
            }, {
                text: " <br>    4   <br><br>    5   <br><br>    6   ",
            }, {
                text: " <br>    7   <br><br>    8   <br><br>    9   ",
            }, ];
            var quote1 = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)];
            document.getElementById("quote1").innerHTML =
                '<p><font size="7">' + quote1.text + '</font></p>';
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <center>
        <div id="quote1"></div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <center>
            <a href="#" onclick="myFunction()">Next</a>
        </center>
    </center>
</body>

</html>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Just trigger the button on page load, or call `myFunction()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call it on page load.

```
window.onload = function(){
   myFunction();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Call the function after page is loaded.

```
<body onload="myFunction()">
```

Answer (score 0):

put the entire stuff in to a function at the end of the doc:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>

<body>
<center>
<div id="quote1"></div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<center>
<a href="#" onclick="randomQuote()">Next</a>
</center>
</center>
</body>

<script>
var randomQuote = function() {
    var quotes = [
       {text:" <br>    1   <br><br>    2   <br><br>    3   ",},
       {text:" <br>    4   <br><br>    5   <br><br>    6   ",},
       {text:" <br>    7   <br><br>    8   <br><br>    9   ",},
     ];
     var quote1 = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)];
     document.getElementById("quote1").innerHTML=
          '<p><font size="7">' + quote1.text + '</font></p>';
 };
 randomQuote();

</script>
</html>
```

The last line will execute the function immediately.